# My CSS static file isn't loading as I expected

Tags: python, html, css, django

I'm following a tutorial on building Django Ecommerce Website and apparently I might have messed up somewhere I can't quite figure out. The `main.css` file seems to be loading incorrectly. I had encountered it before but found a solution. Unfortunately it stopped loading `main.css` correctly.

This is the `main.css`:

```
body{
    background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 98%);
}

h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{
    color:hsl(0, 0%, 30%);
}

.box-element{
    box-shadow:hsl(0, 0%, 80%) 0 0 16px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 10px;
}

.thumbnail{
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: -1px -3px 5px -2px rgba(214,214,214,1);
    -moz-box-shadow: -1px -3px 5px -2px rgba(214,214,214,1);
    box-shadow: -1px -3px 5px -2px rgba(214,214,214,1);
}

.product{
    border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
}

.bg-dark{
    background-color: #4f868c!important;
}

#cart-icon{
    width:25px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 15px;
}

#cart-total{
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    color:#fff;
    background-color: red;
    width: 20px;
    height: 25px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.col-lg-4, .col-lg-6, .col-lg-8, .col-lg-12{
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.btn{
    border-radius: 0;
}

.row-image{
    width: 100px;
}

.form-field{
    width:250px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px;
}

.cart-row{
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-stretch;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ececec;

}

.quantity{
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: 700;
    padding-right:10px;
    

}

.chg-quantity{
    width: 12px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 5px;
    transition:.1s;
}

.chg-quantity:hover{
    opacity: .6;
}


.hidden{
    display: none!important;
}
```

This is settings.py

```
"""
Django settings for ecommerce project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 4.0.3.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-(k^b)u8e!a+2=vm6pc)htxf1f=%o$rm#t#_&8m&840%sl2h54$'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'store.apps.StoreConfig',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'ecommerce.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'ecommerce.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
]

MEDIA_URL = '/images/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/images')

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

This is main.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
<html>
<head>
    <title>Ecom</title>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href=" {% static '/css/main.css' %} ">

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var user = '{{request.user}}'
    </script>

</head>
<body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'store' %}">Ecom</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'store' %}">Store <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
     
        </ul>
        <div class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
            <a href="#"class="btn btn-warning">Login</a>
            
            <a href="{% url 'cart' %}">
                <img  id="cart-icon" src="{% static 'images/cart.png' %}">
            </a>
            <p id="cart-total">0</p>

        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

     <div class="container">
            <br>
            {% block content %}


            {% endblock content %}
         </div>


    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/cart.js' %}"></script>

</body>
</html>

Error
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) main.css
```

Comment: What do you mean by isn't loading correctly? Is it failing to show updates that you've made? Like loading an older version of the file or is it just downright not finding the file?

Comment: Its not loading the file completely

Comment: What happens when you put the path to the css as the href

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this would do the trick?

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/main.css'>
```